# bash-like heredoc for data input

Tags: python, bash

Sometimes it would be handy to test a script that reads data from a file using inline data (so that both the data and the code would be in the same file). In `bash` this can be done with a `heredoc`:

```
while read l;do
    echo $l
done << EOF
test
test2
test3
EOF
```

In some real code there would of course happen something more apart from writing out the lines. Suppose I would do something similar in `python`:

```
def read_file(f):
    for line in f.readlines():
        print(line.replace('\n',''))

with open('input.txt') as f:
    read_file(f)
```

What would be the best way to provide the content of `input.txt` to `read_file()` *inline*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html):

```
from io import StringIO    

f = StringIO('''\
foo
bar
test
''')

read_file(f)
```

The above code works with Python3. In Python2 use:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
```